# Remote PowerShell script doesn't apply Hyper-V Snapshot

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I'm attempting to remotely apply a Hyper-V snapshot through PowerShell. I'm following [Ben Armstrong's guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2011/10/19/applying-a-snapshot-via-powershell-hyper-v.aspx) for this.

I'm in Server 2008 R2, by the way.

In a nutshell:

Connecting to remote server:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain\user", $password)
Enter-PSSession -Computer computerName -Credential $cred
```

This works just fine. I've tested this remote connection by creating a folder on the machine.

Applying the snapshot:

```
$HyperVServer = Read-Host "Specify the Hyper-V Server to use (enter '.' for the local computer)"

# Prompt for the virtual machine to use
$VMName = Read-Host "Specify the name of the virtual machine"

# Prompt for the name of the snapshot to apply
$SnapshotName = Read-Host "Specify the name of the snapshot to apply"

# Get the management service
$VMMS = gwmi -namespace root\virtualization Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService -computername $HyperVServer

# Get the virtual machine object
$VM = gwmi MSVM_ComputerSystem -filter "ElementName='$VMName'" -namespace "root\virtualization" -computername $HyperVServer

# Find the snapshot that we want to apply
$Snapshot = gwmi -Namespace root\virtualization -Query "Associators Of {$VM} Where AssocClass=Msvm_ElementSettingData ResultClass=Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData" | where {$_.ElementName -eq $SnapshotName} | select -first 1

# Apply the snapshot
$VMMS.ApplyVirtualSystemSnapshot($VM, $Snapshot)
```

I execute these one-by-one, it's finding the VM and the Snapshot just fine, but when I execute the final command, my snapshot is not applied. It doesn't fail either, no error message.

I do get the following, however, after executing the final command:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 32775
```

This return value indicates `Invalid state for this operation (32775)` according to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). What does that mean? How do I fix this to actually apply the snapshot?

The VM is currently in a running state, so I tried again with the VM shut down and the snapshot applied properly.

How can I force the snapshot to apply with the VM in a running state?

Comment: Have you tried taking the snapshot "manually" through the Hyper-V UI? "Invalid state for this operation" seems to mean what it says - e.g. I've seen it occur if there was a merge in progress (which can't be so in your case though).

Comment: @Al-Muhandis There's no issue with taking snapshots, this post doesn't concern *taking* the snapshot. The issue is with *applying* the snapshot through PowerShell while the VM is in a running state.

Comment: Right, applying it sorry. Have you tried applying it through the UI?

Comment: @Al-Muhandis Yep, I'm able to apply snapshots manually while the VM is in a running state no problem. I only get `Invalid state for this operation` when I try to do the same thing via WMI/PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

The article clearly states that:

> One thing to be aware of is that this operation will fail if the virtual machine is running when you try to apply the snapshot – the virtual machine needs to be turned off or put into a saved state first.

`ApplyVirtualSystemSnapshot` doesn't work remotely with running VM's